# OpenQASeleniumWebDriver fails to start socket at 45000ms

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I am new to Selenium and Web Driver and I have come across the following when using FireFox:

"OpenQA.Selenim.WebDriver Exception: Failed to start up socket within 45000ms. Attempted to connect to address 127.0.0.1.7055"

My Selenium Driver is version 2.53.1.0 and Firefox version is 48.0.1

I am only trying to open a page and type the google url just to make sure that my code works in Visual Studio 2015.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Tasos

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38748675/selenium-2-53-1-does-not-work-on-firefox-48/38749354#38749354

Comment: Thanks very much for pointing towards the right direction. The issue I had has been solved now.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to write a few more details about the solution in case another stack overflow user comes across the same issue. The following steps worked for me:

1.Followed the link that Saurabh mentioned & downloaded the geckodriver exe file from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

2.Renamed the file from 'geckodriver' to 'wires'

3.Put the file at the Bin > Debug folder of my Visual Studio Unit Test project

4.Added the following lines of code in the cs file of my project:

```
  FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
  service.FirefoxBinaryPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe";
  driver = new FirefoxDriver(service);
```